# AttributeError throwing up which says list object has no attribute lower

Tags: python, string, nlp, nltk

I am working on an example where training data and training labels are lists, but when I fit on it on a code, it throws an error. I guess, the problem is with the text pre-processing class.

Below is the code, where I created a pipeline, but it say expected str or bytes like object or sometimes, list has not attribute lower.

```
import string

from nltk.corpus import stopwords as sw
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class NLTKPreprocessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, stopwords=None, punct=None,
                 lower=False, strip=True):
        self.lower      = lower
        self.strip      = strip
        self.stopwords  = stopwords or set(sw.words('english'))
        self.punct      = punct or set(string.punctuation)
        self.lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def inverse_transform(self, X):
        return [" ".join(doc) for doc in X]

    def transform(self, X):
        return [
            list(self.tokenize(doc)) for doc in X
        ]

    def tokenize(self, document):
        # Break the document into sentences
        for sent in sent_tokenize(document):
            # Break the sentence into part of speech tagged tokens
            for token, tag in pos_tag(wordpunct_tokenize(sent)):
                # Apply preprocessing to the token
                token = token.lower() if self.lower else token
                token = token.strip() if self.strip else token
                token = token.strip('_') if self.strip else token
                token = token.strip('*') if self.strip else token

                # If stopword, ignore token and continue
                if token in self.stopwords:
                    continue

                # If punctuation, ignore token and continue
                if all(char in self.punct for char in token):
                    continue

                # Lemmatize the token and yield
                lemma = self.lemmatize(token, tag)
                yield lemma

    def lemmatize(self, token, tag):
        tag = {
            'N': wn.NOUN,
            'V': wn.VERB,
            'R': wn.ADV,
            'J': wn.ADJ
        }.get(tag[0], wn.NOUN)

        return self.lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, tag)
```

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

text_clf = Pipeline([('preprocess', NLTKPreprocessor()),
                     ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True,use_idf=True)),
                     ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='l2',
                                           alpha=1e-3, random_state=42)),
])
```

```
#---show only the best performace results: accuracy, other metrics, and confusion matrix
text_clf3.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = text_clf3.predict(X_test)
print ('Accuracy Score (%):', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100)

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred,
    target_names=docs_data.target_names))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get error because of this method.

```
def transform(self, X):
    return [
        list(self.tokenize(doc)) for doc in X
    ]
```

X is a dataframe, and when you iterate dataframe you get indexes of each row. Therefore you get 0 on first iteration and then sent_tokenizer fails because it expects something else.

I am not sure about entire pipeline. But you can fix this one step like this. Note, this would work only with one column.

```
def transform(self, X):
    return [
        list(self.tokenize(doc[0])) for doc in X.values
    ]
```

method above works with the following fit inputs.

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame([['asfas saf asf. dwqdwqwd '],['asdasdasd32d23  wedw ed wed. dwqdwq. ']])
y_train = [[1], [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess (I'm not that familiar with extending the sklearn classes): Can the problem be here? Seems like you are overriding the parent method by not fitting anything and just returning the class object.

```
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self
```